# split datetime from array in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

my problem is to get date from array. but there is a time from it.

i get data from model

```
$data['result'] = $this->MTransaksi->cekpengembalian($id_transaksi);
```

and i want to get datetime

```
$date4 = $data['result']->tanggal_kembali;
```

after get the datetime i should split it with explode in php function

```
$splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$date4);
```

and just get the date from it

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($splitTimeStamp));
```

but the result in view looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1owf.png)

so this is full code i wrote

```
$data['result'] = $this->MTransaksi->cekpengembalian($id_transaksi);
$date4 = $data['result']->tanggal_kembali;
$splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$date4);
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($splitTimeStamp));
```

just want to split date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the code as the `explode()` return an array.

Below I have assigned the array parameters to separate variables and you can use them individually.

```
$data['result'] = $this->MTransaksi->cekpengembalian($id_transaksi);
$date4 = $data['result']->tanggal_kembali;
$splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$date4);
$dateObject = $splitTimeStamp[0];
$timeObject = $splitTimeStamp[1];
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateObject));
```

NOTE: You didn't mention your $date4 how it looks otherwise could have provided a more concrete answer.

Hope it helps

Comment: if i write echo from variable $date4. its show 2023-01-19

Comment: still, the solution will work. in case the `tanggal_kembali` does not contains timestamp